# Adding a package to a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `VueClipboard` in my app, with instructions that say to add the following (ive seen similar with other packages):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueClipboard from 'vue-clipboard2';
Vue.use(VueClipboard);
```

But I want to use it in one of my components, should it be added in my base app.js file or in my components file?

If it needs adding to the component file, any harm in reimporting vue?

Comment: When the component is used in up to 3 components in my point of view it must be imported into the <script> </script> of the component itself that will use, past 3 I would make a global import. The problem of re-importing, if it is not structured correctly, your build can be very large, due to many imports.

Comment: If you are using it in multiple places then import it in main file then you will not have to import it again in any component.